# How to compute huge diagonal matrix inverse (dim 14000*14000)

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-inverse

How to compute the inverse of a huge (dim 14000*14000) matrix?
I am trying that with R and an error message has been shown as :

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 762.9 Mb
```

I know that indicates a failure to obtain memory.
Any help would be appreciated.

Even when i tried to invert a scalar identity matrix, R can not solve it. The inverse of scalar identity matrix will be the same matrix, but R can not solve it either.

```
> solve(diag(1,10000,10000))
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 762.9 Mb
```

Comment: Also note that for diagonal `m` it is simply `1 / m`.

Comment: If your matrix is *not* sparse this will simply be impossible (or at least very, very, very difficult).  Depending on what you are trying to do, there are often computational shortcuts to solving the problem that do not actually require inverting the matrix (e.g. solving linear systems, computing eigenvalues, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

For large [sparse matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix), use the [**Matrix** package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/index.html):

```
library(Matrix)

## Construct a memory-efficient representation of a large, sparse, diagonal matrix
dmat <- Diagonal(x=1:14000)

## Finding the inverse is fast and painless
system.time(dmat.inv <- solve(dmat))
#   user  system elapsed 
#      0       0       0 

## Check  that it worked
dmat.inv[c(1:3, 13998:14000), c(1:3, 13998:14000)]
# 6 x 6 diagonal matrix of class "ddiMatrix"
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]      [,4]         [,5]         [,6]        
# [1,]    1    .         .            .            .            .
# [2,]    .  0.5         .            .            .            .
# [3,]    .    . 0.3333333            .            .            .
# [4,]    .    .         . 7.143878e-05            .            .
# [5,]    .    .         .            . 7.143367e-05            .
# [6,]    .    .         .            .            . 7.142857e-05
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, be sure to use a 64 bit version of R and a  machine with planty of RAM.

Although matrix inversion is a computationally complex operation requiring O(n^3) arithmetic operations, it is far from impossible for n = 10000 and even n = 16000. On my not very modern PC, running R with Intel® Math Kernel Library (Revolution R) I observe the following.

For n = 10000 it runs in 1.5 minutes and uses 3.2 GB of RAM:

```
system.time({
  z = solve(diag(1,10000,10000))
});

  user  system elapsed 
341.89    0.63   87.22
```

For n = 16000 it finishes in 6 minutes and uses 8GB of RAM.

```
system.time({
  z = solve(diag(1,16000,16000))
});

   user  system elapsed 
1388.80    2.34  353.95
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basic algebra: if your `X` matrix is indeed diagonal, the inverse `Y` is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are `Y_{i,i} = 1/X_{i,i}`.

So simply do:

```
x = diag(rnorm(14E3))
inv = diag(1/diag(x))
```